# mustache how to get element in array by index

Tags: mustache, scalate

how to get element value by array in mustache
object

```
    Map(name -> zzzzzzzzzzzzzzz, 
 pageUrl -> /novokuzneck/zum-zum-dvernye-i-okonnye-resheniya/contacts, 
 organiztionUrl -> http://192.168.0.106/c/1245678/, 
 phones -> List(
    Map(phone -> +7333333333, comment -> adsdas), 
    Map(phone -> 81234567, comment -> test), 
    Map(phone -> 822222222, comment -> test2)), 

)
```

how to get

```
<p>{{phones.0.phone}}</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
{{#phones}}
      <p>{{index}} {{phone}}<p>
{{/phones}}
```